# Can there be a race between signalfd and sigaction?

Tags: linux, signals, posix

The classical way to specify a handler for a certain signal is via `sigaction`. Linux additionally provides the `signalfd` functionality, where we can connect signals to a file descriptor and then apply select/(e)poll to that descriptor, which perfectly fits the concept of many event loop-driven systems.

I am wondering what happens / should happen when both mechanisms collide. Can there be race conditions? On the signalfd manpage (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) we read:

> Normally, the set of signals to be received via the file descriptor
>   should be blocked using sigprocmask(2), to prevent the signals being
>   handled according to their default dispositions.

So, it says "normally" we use the signal mask in order to prevent the (default) handler from processing a signal. It does not say that we **have to** block that signal when we have a file descriptor connected to it. Unfortunately, the man page does not specify what happens when we don't block the signal.

This looks like poorly defined behavior. I do not believe that this is actually not well-defined and am wondering if anyone here knows *i*) were I can find a detailed specification about how the system should behave or *ii*) how it behaves.

What I am specifically interested in, is this order of execution:

1. signalfd for a certain signal, including blockage of this signal
2. unblockage of this signal
3. sigaction for this signal (default handler or custom handler)

Is this undefined behavior or is there a standard/specification for what must happen? Does the handler always take precedence over the file descriptor? Is the handler called *and* the file descriptor fires off an event? Does setting `sigaction` change the signal mask, rendering step (2) unnecessary?

I could try to derive the actual behavior from systematic tests involving actual code. However, I of course prefer to find a detailed piece of documentation and consider that I was not able to find the right reference myself.

Comment: This seems to come down to the question of whether the use of  *normally* in the above description is justified.  Ignoring the issue that there is nothing *stopping* anyone from not first blocking the signals, is there actually a use case for *not* blocking the signals before using `signalfd` or `sigwaitinfo`?  It seems to me the whole point of these calls is to operate on *pending* signals to circumvent their delivery dispositions.  So I'll lay it out there: does anyone know of case where unblocked signals and either of these calls makes good sense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`signalfd` behaves identically to `sigwaitinfo`, except you get to access the information via a file descriptor. This means that a `signalfd` receives signals *synchronously*, and signal handlers (or whichever is the default disposition) are called *first*.

**Source:** TLPI chapters 22.10 and 22.11 (M. Kerrisk).

The behavior is well-defined, but not necessarily what one would expect, and the manpage is worded rather badly. Saying *"normally... should"* suggests that either you don't really have to, or worse that the author isn't quite sure.
If you want it to work "properly", i.e. the way you'd normally expect (see, I used "normally" too), you do have to block the signals. Otherwise, the signal will be available via the file descriptor, but a handler will still be called first (which is entirely legitimate, but most people would probably consider this "weird behavior").

Thus, there exist two different race conditions. One condition is the one you ask about, but although the behavior is a bit unexpected, it is well-defined and (kind of) documented, and if you think about it, then it isn't strictly a race condition. Rather it is a kind of "double delivery".
The other race condition is the possibility of a signal arriving after you created the `signalfd` but before you blocked the signal. It is very unlikely, but in principle, this could happen. Luckily, the solution is easy, you can block the signal *first* and then create the file descriptor (which will then immediately be ready if a signal arrived in between).

The sequence of commands that you named (create file descriptor, unblock, then `sigaction`) has a similar race condition. You should first install a handler and then unblock, or a signal may be delivered before the handler is there. But that's irrespective of `signalfd`. The file descriptor could still be used to read the signal in any case, but the default disposition might kill the process if a signal arrives between unblocking and installing the handler.

Comment: Very helpful answer, this is why I love StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: I would say `signalfd` does not behave identically to `sigwaitinfo` in a threaded environment.  `signalfd` is global to the process, and `sigwaitinfo` is called in individual threads.  In order to get `sigwaitinfo` to reliably receive signals its waiting on, those signals must be blocked in all other threads. Great answer otherwise!

Comment: I don't think that is a difference, but rather an example of how they behave the same: the man page seems to indicate that for signalfd to work reliably, the signals must also be blocked on all threads, just like sigwaitinfo.